# How to issue a post requests within parse method while using async instead of inline_requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to use async to get rid of additional callback within parse method. I know there is a library [inline_requests](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-inline-requests/) which can do it.

However, I wish to stick with async. What I can't userstand is how I can issue a post requests within parse method.

When I issue a post request using inline_requests, I get success:

```
import scrapy
from inline_requests import inline_requests

class HkexNewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hkexnews"
    start_url = "http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_url,callback=self.parse_item)

    @inline_requests
    def parse_item(self,response):
        payload = {item.css('::attr(name)').get(default=''):item.css('::attr(value)').get(default='') for item in response.css("input[name]")}
        payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'btnSearch'
        payload['txtStockCode'] = '00001'
        payload['txtParticipantID'] = 'A00001'

        resp = yield scrapy.FormRequest(self.start_url, formdata=payload, dont_filter=True)
        total_value = resp.css(".ccass-search-total > .shareholding > .value::text").get()
        yield {"Total Value":total_value}
```

While trying to issue a post requests using async, I get None as result:

```
async def parse(self,response):
    payload = {item.css('::attr(name)').get(default=''):item.css('::attr(value)').get(default='') for item in response.css("input[name]")}
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'btnSearch'
    payload['txtStockCode'] = '00001'
    payload['txtParticipantID'] = 'A00001'

    request = response.follow(self.start_url,method='POST',body=payload, dont_filter=True)
    resp = await self.crawler.engine.download(request, self)
    total_value = resp.css(".ccass-search-total > .shareholding > .value::text").get()
    yield {"Total Value":total_value}
```

> > How can I fetch result using the latter approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import scrapy


class HkexNewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hkexnews"
    start_urls = ['http://www.hkexnews.hk/sdw/search/searchsdw.aspx']

    async def parse(self, response):
        payload = {item.css('::attr(name)').get(default=''): item.css('::attr(value)').get(default='') for item in response.css("input[name]")}
        payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'btnSearch'
        payload['txtStockCode'] = '00001'
        payload['txtParticipantID'] = 'A00001'

        request = scrapy.FormRequest(self.start_urls[0], formdata=payload, dont_filter=True)
        resp = await self.crawler.engine.download(request, self)
        total_value = resp.css(".ccass-search-total > .shareholding > .value::text").get()
        yield {"Total Value": total_value}
```

Output:

```py
{'Total Value': '2,546,531,648'}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @SuperUser, for your working solution. It's embarrassing that I couldn't figure this out myself.

Comment: @robots.txt It happens to the best =)